# File IO From a JAR File

Tags: java, maven, jar, io

How do I both create and read files from outside the JAR file? Should I even be using a jar file to run a program if I want the application to be distributed?

I'm trying to write a Java program to draw tilemaps, and I want to save some files. I'm also trying to learn how to properly structure my program, so I formatted it as a Maven project. I can do that easily from the src/main/java/ .java files, but it gets confusing when I build the program into a JAR file.

I've been researching ways to access external folders when running a program through a JAR file and I cannot find a clear answer.

Comment: You read files with the `Files` and `Path` class in Java. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Although I can access them when running the .java file (I use Eclipse), the paths seems to be different when I compile the program into a JAR file. The JAR file is in a different folder within the project, so the relative paths to the files I want to access are different.I'm confused by how I should determine the relative path and if it is even possible to access file FROM INSIDE a JAR file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Additonally keep in mind that StackOverflow community is not a free coding service Currently you are not asking any question.

Comment: The "current" path is an OS artifact, and may not exist in all environments.  Certainly the concept of "relative to the program" or "relative to the jar file"  is completely meaningless.  You must provide externally (configuration) a way for the program to determine absolute paths.

Comment: Is using absolute paths a common practice in java development? I just assumed that it isn't and that absolute paths can't always be obtained.

Comment: You need to distinguish between "files that are part of your program" and "files that the users of your program create / modify". "Files that are part of your program" are created by you, are resources and distributed with your progam. So they can be placed into the jar file and loaded using `Class.getResourceAsStream()` when needed. "Files that the users of your program create / modify" are external files and you have no choice but to ask the user which file he wants to work with (and thereby also specifying to path to the files).

Comment: I'm trying to create the file automatically using File.createNewFile() because I can't store empty files in a GitHub repository. Could I create and access files through the JAR file that way?

Comment: You cannot use `File` and `FileInputStream` and the like to access resources in a JAR file.  You read resources in a JAR using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` ... and you don't write them ... 'cos the JAR file is typically read-only and/or not owned by the user.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to distribute standalone applications is either:

- Via the OS's built in app distribution system, such as `apt` on debian linux installations, or app stores. If that's not an option (and it's kind of a drag to figure out how to do that with java apps, and requires building something specific for each and every OS you target)
- By having the static app data (so, the executables, i.e. the jar files, as well as any static data that wouldn't ever change. Think, say, the 'save' icon for a desktop text editor application. That's not something you'd generally allow a user to change) in one place, and any user data (such as a text file they wrote), or any data that your app already ships with but *is* user-changable (such as config files), in a different place. Crucially, proper OS hygiene says that the app should be unable to write to its own static files.

Good OSes work exactly like this. For a very long time, the standard deployment model on windows OS was to have `C:\Program Files\SomeApp` which contained *both* the app's static files/data as well as e.g. config files and the like, and that folder was writable to the app. No wonder, the general security mindset of all involved parties for windows installations (users, supplier (i.e. microsoft), and developers) didn't take security very seriously.

Fortunately, even windows woke up to reality on this and the more modern take on windows is... still to do that, but to have config and user files elsewhere, e.g. in a `My Documents` folder.

You should do the same thing.

Once you do it that way, your question immediately becomes irrelevant - there is no need to know how to write into a jar file, because you shouldn't do that in the first place. The jar file is where the static data lives.

### I have template data

Template data is the notion that your app should ship 'out of the box' with a non-blank base entry but that the user IS allowed to change it if they wish. For example, imagine you really did have a text editor whose save icon can be configured in the app's settings pane. You don't want it to ship without an icon at all, of course.

In this case, you stick the standard save icon in your app and you either treat 'user-configurable save icon is not there' as '... so then load the default icon from the jar, via `.getResource`', or as '... so then I shall copy over the template (the default save icon in the jar) to the proper location on disk, not in a jar, in the user's home dir someplace, so they know what to edit'.

That last one is particularly convenient for config files, where you want the config file to be editable by the user and have lots of comment notes so the user knows what each setting does and which values they can change them to.

### I want the old way, how do I get my own jar file's path?

Easy enough, but it requires a light bit of hackery. You ask for your own class via getResource, e.g:

```
class MyApp {
  public static Path getPathToMyOwnJar() {
    String url = MyApp.class.getResource("MyApp.class").toString();
    if (url.startsWith("jar:")) {
      return new File(new URI(url.substring(4, url.indexOf('!')))).toPath();
    }
    if (url.startsWith("file:")) {
      File f = new File(url.toURI()).toPath();
      // do some basic coding on walking up the tree for each package
      // element. i.e. turn `C:\Program Files\MyApp\bin\com\foo\MyApp.class`
      // into `C:\Program Files\MyApp`.
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Own classpath source is neither a jar nor a file, but: " + url + " -- cannot determine own path");
  }
}
```

This uses the fact that you can always ask 'where is my own class file' and the URL returned is generally `url:file://path/to/yourjar.jar!/com/foo/YourClass.class`, or `file://path/to/classpath/bin/com/foo/YourClass.class` depending on whether your app is running as jar or straight from the file system. We can parse that and break out the data.

I'm not quite sure *why* you would want to do this; the place you find is not necessarily a good place to write files.

Generally, `.getResource` works regardless of whether your app is in jars or just as class files on disk or however else it's deployed, that's the point: `getResource` looks in the same place that `java.exe` itself looks for class files. Where-ever that might be. This mechanism (find me a resource; look in the same place you look for class files) can **only** read and can **not** list, you can just ask for a specific file, that's it.

To access external folders, that's.. just file access, check the [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package for the API you can use; you can access whatever you want with this. Note that `System.getProperty("user.home")` gets you the user's home dir, i.e. `/home/username` on linux, `/Users/username` on mac, `C:\Users\username` on windows. Toss that through `Paths.get()` and `.resolve()` your way from there to write files to the user's homedir, which is where you should be writing them (preferably in a sane subfolder).

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I started playing around with getResources and properties files and then realized again that I shouldn't be putting the properties file in the jar's resources bc I wouldn't be able to rewrite it. 

Edit: I mean to mention that I'm now trying to save the user's preferred directory for the app's user files, which is why I have the properties folder, but realized that I don't know how to relocate it bc I planned on having the directory saved in the properties, which itself is in said directory. 
TLDR; How do I save a user-defined path without hardcoding a path?

Comment: By having a config entry in a place where config entries go. You can use [the preferences API](https://www.amitph.com/introduction-to-java-preferences-api/) which writes to registry on windows and a `.file` in userhome elsewhere. Or do it yourself - `Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".myapp")`.